# Send custom data pushPlugin cordova php

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

This is a code to send message and data in a notification.

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $this->devices,
        'data'             => array(
                "message"      => $message,
                "msgcnt"       => "8",
                "collapse_key" => "dffbb")
        );
```

The problem I am facing is I cannot send anything else beside `msgcnt` and `collapse_key`.

The alert gives undefined for example

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $this->devices,
        'data'             => array(
                "message"      => $message,
                "msgcnt"       => "8",
                "collapse_key" => "dffbb",
                "test_field"   => "test")
        );
```

Comment: I've improved formatting; however there is still lost explanation after *for example*... Please explain about *undefined*. What is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another array with custom data like this:

```
$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $this->devices,
                'data'              => array("message" => array("text_message" => $message, "test_field" => "test"),
                                            "msgcnt"=>"8",
                                            "collapse_key"=>"dffbb",
                                              )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it the data which gets returned goes into another array index named payload so if you want to access it in javascript you can try.

```
alert(e.payload.test_field);
```